# Switching timer delay, non accumulative

Tags: timer, 555, delay

I am trying to build a 555-timer that delays the switch of an input signal, both ways. When input goes high there should be a delay before output goes high, when input goes low there should be a delay before output goes low. If the input switches for a too short amount of time it should not switch the output at all.

[image]

I hope I am making myself clear here. I guess I need to use two 555 timers, I have been fiddling around but have made no progress.

Comment: Basically, what you try to do is called „debouncing“. You could more easily do that with a simple resistor and a capacitor. Signal high will charge the capacitor through the resistor, while signal low will discharge it. The time constant will be T=R*C (in seconds).

Comment: @StefanWyss Thanks for that explanation. I did not know that it is called "debouncing" and when I search for this together with 555 I get much more information than before. Since I am looking at multiple minutes and not seconds I would need really large capacitors so I think a 555-timer is the way to go this time.